# How to get argv as LPWSTR* and not char** from command line arguments?

Tags: c++, winapi, argv, unicode-string

I am writing a small C++ program which gets as input from the program command line, a string to later be passed to another function.

The problem is that this function **expects to get a LPWSTR (`wchar_t*`) type variable**, and the [regular](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) `char** argv` is an array of elements from **the type of `char*`**.

Is there any way to get the argv variable as a `LPWSTR*` type?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to transform a string `char` into a string of `wchar_t`?  Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576846/convert-ascii-string-to-unicode-windows-pure-c/11576927

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks. This is another approach but seems like the one with `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` is simpler in the case of the argv array.

Comment: To get the argv variable as a `LPWSTR*`, use `wmain` instead of `main`.

Comment: Your options: `1` Use [wmain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain) as pointed out by Raymond. `2` Use the symbols [__argv, __wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) provided by Microsoft's CRT implementation. `3` Call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) on the return value of [GetCommandLineW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution can be acheived by combining both `GetCommandLineW()` and `CommandLineToArgvW()` in the following way:

```cpp
int main() {
    int argc = 0;
    LPWSTR* pArgvW = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    // use pArgvW as needed...
    LocalFree(pArgvW);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Reading [GetCommandLineW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew) and [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw) documentation might also help.