# How to Use UTF-8 Collation in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

I've migrated a database from mysql to SQL Server (politics), original mysql database using UTF8.

Now I read https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset that SQL Server 2008 doesn't support utf8, is this a joke?

The SQL Server hosts multiple databases, mostly Latin-encoded. Since the migrated db is intended for web publishing, I want to keep the utf8-encoding. Have I missed something or do I need to enc/dec at application level?

Comment: Actually there is no problem with using UTF8, by creating SQLCLR UDF and you can download from Microsoft the code. check this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160893(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Worth noting that Java, JavaScript, DotNet and Windows all use UTF-16 internally, so if your website is to be coded in any of those then you are saving a conversion to UTF16.

Comment: If it helps, you can pretend that SQL Server internally stores text as UTF-8; and the driver converts it back to UTF-16 when you retrieve it. You could also pretend that SQL Server stores the text as UCS-32. The internal storage format is an irrelevant implementation detail. What is important is that databases return unicode character data as UTF-16 (matching your programming environment).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No! It's not a joke.

Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

> Character data types that are either fixed-length, nchar, or
>   variable-length, nvarchar, Unicode data and use the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

And also here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

> The older UCS-2 (2-byte Universal Character Set) is a similar
>   character encoding that was superseded by UTF-16 in version 2.0 of the
>   Unicode standard in July 1996.

Comment: Ok. Can the mssql-client translate to the outside UTF8-world?

Comment: `mssql-client` can be everything. Java, .NET, C, PHP, etc... what do mean with client?

Comment: Client : sqlsrv extension under php. Robert puts it i clear text here:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldriverforphp/thread/e6e506cd-e7f8-42a2-87fb-4e19f8fa9368, will evaluate and post results.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the delay but thanks for the reps, using  sqlsrv_connect(,array("CharacterSet" => "UTF-8").. in connection string works fine. PDO is out, right?

Answer (score 44):

UTF-8 is not a character set, it's an encoding. The character set for UTF-8 is Unicode. If you want to store Unicode text you use the `nvarchar` data type.

If the database would use UTF-8 to store text, you would still not get the text out as encoded UTF-8 data, you would get it out as decoded text.

You can easily store UTF-8 encoded text in the database, but then you don't store it as text, you store it as binary data (`varbinary`).

Comment: Thanks for input. There's more to learn around this, looking at for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/whats-the-difference-between-unicode-and-utf8

Comment: I can't get my head around this. "The character set for UTF8 is Unicode"?? Isn't utf8 way broader than unicode. Saving Dauðalogn in unicode vs utf8 gives different results: (EF BB BF) 44 61 75 C3 B0 61 6C 6F 67 6E vs
\u0044\u0061\u0075\u00f0\u0061\u006c\u006f\u0067\u006e

Comment: @user247245: UTF-8 is the encoding and Unicode is the character set. UTF-8 is one way of saving Unicode. What you have used to represent the Unicode is escape codes used in string literals, that's not normally how you represent Unicode as a file. UTF-32 would be the closest translation directly from Uncode to a file format, where each character code is saved as a 32 bit number.

Comment: Can you please explain why the third letter in the example above is represented in UTF8 as C3 B0 and in unicode as simply F0 . Thanks for  your help.

Comment: @user247245: Character codes between 8 and 11 bits are encoded as `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` in UTF-8 (where `x` represents data bits), so the character code `F0` (`00011110000` as 11 bits) is encoded as `11000011 10110000` (putting `00011` from the character code in the first byte and `110000` in the second) which is `C3 B0`.

Answer (score 30):

Looks like this will be finally supported in the SQL Server 2019!
[SQL Server 2019 - whats new?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#databaseengine)

> From BOL:
>
> UTF-8 support
>
> Full support for the widely used UTF-8 character encoding as an import
> or export encoding, or as database-level or column-level collation for
> text data. UTF-8 is allowed in the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` datatypes, and is
> enabled when creating or changing an object’s collation to a collation
> with the `UTF8` suffix.
>
> For example,`LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AS_SC` to
> `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_SC_UTF8`. UTF-8 is only available to Windows
> collations that support supplementary characters, as introduced in SQL
> Server 2012. `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` allow UTF-16 encoding only, and remain
> unchanged.
>
> This feature may provide significant storage savings, depending on the
> character set in use. For example, changing an existing column data
> type with ASCII strings from `NCHAR(10)` to `CHAR(10)` using an UTF-8
> enabled collation, translates into nearly 50% reduction in storage
> requirements. This reduction is because `NCHAR(10)` requires 22 bytes
> for storage, whereas `CHAR(10)` requires 12 bytes for the same Unicode
> string.

2019-05-14 update:

Documentation seems to be updated now and explains our options staring in MSSQL 2019 in section "[Collation and Unicode Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sqlallproducts-allversions)".

2019-07-24 update:

[Article by Pedro Lopes](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Introducing-UTF-8-support-for-Azure-SQL-Database/ba-p/757748) - Senior Program Manager @ Microsoft about introducing UTF-8 support for Azure SQL Database

Comment: Caveat Emptor: https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/

Answer (score 9):

Two UDF to deal with UTF-8 in T-SQL:

```
CREATE Function UcsToUtf8(@src nvarchar(MAX)) returns varchar(MAX) as
begin
    declare @res varchar(MAX)='', @pi char(8)='%[^'+char(0)+'-'+char(127)+']%', @i int, @j int
    select @i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    while @i>0
    begin
        select @j=unicode(substring(@src,@i,1))
        if @j<0x800     select @res=@res+left(@src,@i-1)+char((@j&1984)/64+192)+char((@j&63)+128)
        else            select @res=@res+left(@src,@i-1)+char((@j&61440)/4096+224)+char((@j&4032)/64+128)+char((@j&63)+128)
        select @src=substring(@src,@i+1,datalength(@src)-1), @i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    end
    select @res=@res+@src
    return @res
end

CREATE Function Utf8ToUcs(@src varchar(MAX)) returns nvarchar(MAX) as
begin
    declare @i int, @res nvarchar(MAX)=@src, @pi varchar(18)
    select @pi='%[à-ï][€-¿][€-¿]%',@i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    while @i>0 select @res=stuff(@res,@i,3,nchar(((ascii(substring(@src,@i,1))&31)*4096)+((ascii(substring(@src,@i+1,1))&63)*64)+(ascii(substring(@src,@i+2,1))&63))), @src=stuff(@src,@i,3,'.'), @i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    select @pi='%[Â-ß][€-¿]%',@i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    while @i>0 select @res=stuff(@res,@i,2,nchar(((ascii(substring(@src,@i,1))&31)*64)+(ascii(substring(@src,@i+1,1))&63))), @src=stuff(@src,@i,2,'.'),@i=patindex(@pi,@src collate Latin1_General_BIN)
    return @res
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that as of Microsoft SQL Server 2016, UTF-8 is supported by [`bcp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), [`BULK_INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), and [`OPENROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx).

Addendum 2016-12-21: SQL Server 2016 SP1 now enables Unicode Compression (and most other previously Enterprise-only features) for all versions of MS SQL including Standard and Express. This is not the same as UTF-8 support, but it yields a similar benefit if the goal is disk space reduction for Western alphabets.

Comment: But not OPENQUERY? I wonder if this is why I'm having issues migrating CLOB data from Oracle using OPENQUERY.