# Using a SQL Server Database and Character Sets

Tags: sonarqube

According to documentation for SonarQube database backend set up, database must be set to utf-8. Our DBA has done some research and does not see an option to change this for particular DBs. Currently it is UTF-16 by default. Is the UTF-8 setting a "must have" for SonarQube? How does one change encoding for particular schemas in SQL Server? We have not had much luck in SQL Server documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies into the fact that UTF-16 is a superset of UTF-8 and that is why you can't change charset to UTF-8 in SQL server.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512687/sql-server-utf8-howto) and its answers for a more detailed explanation of this.