# Storing ???? in database is encoding issue?

Tags: php, sql-server, nginx, laravel-5.3, sqlsrv

I have MS SQL database with collation set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. I am connecting to the database through PHP (Nginx server on Freebsd OS). When I am trying to save characters like `ജെയിംസ്, جیمز` etc it is storing as `????`. My default_charset is `UTF-8` in PHP.

**UPDATE**:
When I tried it from my local Windows env, it was storing the characters successfully. But from the Freebsd environment it is having problem. Below is the stored procedure call from Windows and Freebsd environment respectively.

Trace from Windows machine:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
declare @p14 int
set @p14=0
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 nvarchar(15),@P2 nvarchar(16),@P3 nvarchar(10),@P4 nvarchar(max),@P5 nvarchar(max),@P6 char(1),@P7 char(1),@P8 nvarchar(max),@P9 int,@P10 nvarchar(1),@P11 int OUTPUT',N'EXEC ValidateFBLogin_sp @p_UserName = @P1, @p_Email = @P2, @p_FBID = @P3, @p_DeviceToken = @P4, @p_IPAddress = @P5, @p_Latitude = @P6, @p_Longitude = @P7, @p_EndpointArn = @P8, @p_UserAccountTypeID = @P9, @p_DeviceType = @P10, @p_ErrID = @P11 OUTPUT',N'ആഷ്ലി',N'ashley@gmail.com',N'67463sgs7s',N'',N'',NULL,NULL,N'',2,N'1',@p14 output
select @p1, @p14
```

Trace from Freebsd:

```
EXEC ValidateFBLogin_sp 
@p_UserName = 'ആഷ്ലി', @p_Email = 'ashley@gmail.com', @p_FBID = '45534552', @p_DeviceToken = '', 
@p_IPAddress = '', @p_Latitude = NULL, @p_Longitude = NULL, 
    @p_EndpointArn = '', @p_UserAccountTypeID = 2, 
@p_DeviceType = '1', @p_ErrID = 0
```

From windows it is prep-ending N with the in param p_UserName but in Freebsd it is not.

**Update2**: Regarding database connection from `PHP` Laravel5.3 Framework

Connection parameters: config/database.php

```
return [
'sqlsrvstaging' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'host' => 'XXXXX',
    'database' => 'XXXXX',
    'username' => 'XXXXX',
    'password' => 'XXXXX',
    'prefix' => '',
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'strict' => false,
    'pooling' => false,
    ]
];
```

Code is  `$this->pdo = DB::connection('sqlsrvstaging')->getPdo();`

Comment: Use a Unicode character set to store UTF-8 encoded text: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32128634/1363190

Comment: Hello, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works in PHP, but you can try this:

- change the type of the column to `nvarchar(xx)`,
- when doing insert or update, use the N prefix.

Like this:

```
insert into Table(C1, C2)
values (N'123456789', N'Name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Latin-1 is a single-byte charset designed for Western Europe languages (Spanish, French...). It cannot physically store random Unicode characters like the ones you need.

You need to get back to the design table and change the types of the columns involved to its Unicode-aware counterparts (aka "national"), e.g. from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`.

You also need to ensure your PHP connection is properly configured. You don't say what extension you are using but in e.g. the SQLSRV extension you'd do this:

```
sqlsrv_connect($dsn, array(
    // ...
    'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
));
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. Please see my question update

Comment: @KirenSiva Is "tried this" a confirmation that you are using the SQLSRV extension? You still haven't said it explicitly (nor shared any PHP code).

Comment: Sorry I missed it. Please check Update2

Comment: Right, sorry, I know nothing about Laravel.