# PHP SQL Server (MS) stops returning rows with special characters

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a query that is not returning all the rows. I have boiled it down to the description field. Seem like if the description field has special characters it stops returning rows.

I am not sure if it is in this

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))"
```

or in here

```
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($connms, $tsql)
```

Here is an example of the data where it stops. "**PAR, Lacdo 15.6 Inch 360° Prot**" Seems that this is the offending character °

Any help in getting the whole record set to return would be most appreciated.

PHP 7.4.16
sqlsrv 5.9.0

Comment: Does this explain it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512687/how-to-use-utf-8-collation-in-sql-server-database

Comment: Does it stop _retrieving_ or does it stop _displaying_?

Answer (score 0):

What did it was adding this to the connection options **'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8'**

```
$serverName = "192.168.x.x";
$connectionOptions = array(
    "Database" => "database",
    "Uid" => "username",
    "PWD" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    'CharacterSet'=>'UTF-8'
);
$connms = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```