# non-breaking utf-8 0xc2a0 space and preg_replace strange behaviour

Tags: php, regex

In my string I have utf-8 non-breaking space (0xc2a0) and I want to replace it with something else.

When I use

```
$str=preg_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', 'X', $str);
```

it works OK.

But when I use

```
$str=preg_replace('~\x{C2A0}~siu', 'W', $str);
```

non-breaking space is not found (and replaced).

Why? What is wrong with second regexp?

The format `\x{C2A0}` is correct, also I used `u` flag.

Comment: May be because `$str` is not unicode string.

Comment: I came here looking for $str=preg_replace('~\xc2\xa0~', 'X', $str); It's the first time a question has answered by question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Actually the documentation about escape sequences in PHP is wrong. When you use `\xc2\xa0` syntax, it searches for UTF-8 character. But with `\x{c2a0}` syntax, it tries to convert the Unicode sequence to UTF-8 encoded character.

A non breaking space is `U+00A0` (Unicode) but encoded as `C2A0` in UTF-8. So if you try with the pattern `~\x{00a0}~siu`, it will work as expected.

Comment: Hi Newbo. Your answer worked for me, but I still don't understand why. Is it because my nbsp is not UTF-8? My data is coming from a database table with utf8_general_ci character set, so it should be UTF-8 (my character_set_client and character_set_connection are also UTF-8). Do you have a link for more information on this? Thanks.

Comment: [This article](http://rrn.dk/the-difference-between-utf-8-and-unicode) is great to understand more on this subject. There's also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/whats-the-difference-between-unicode-and-utf8) where the former article has been copy/pasted.

Answer (score 15):

I've aggregated previous answers so people can just copy / paste following code to choose their favorite method :

```
$some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces = "some text with 2 non breaking spaces at the beginning";
echo 'Qty non-breaking space : ' . substr_count($some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces, "\xc2\xa0") . '<br>';
echo $some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces . '<br>';

# Method 1 : regular expression
$clean_text = preg_replace('~\x{00a0}~siu', ' ', $some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces);

# Method 2 : convert to bin -> replace -> convert to hex
$clean_text = hex2bin(str_replace('c2a0', '20', bin2hex($some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces)));

# Method 3 : my favorite
$clean_text = str_replace("\xc2\xa0", " ", $some_text_with_non_breaking_spaces);

echo 'Qty non-breaking space : ' . substr_count($clean_text, "\xc2\xa0"). '<br>';
echo $clean_text . '<br>';
```

Comment: The `hex2bin()` variant is dangerous, it will wrongly replace mis-aligned occurences. Consider the hex sequence `0c2a0a` for example.

Answer (score 3):

The two codes do different things in my opinion: the first `\xc2\xa0` will replace TWO characters, `\xc2` and `\xa0` with nothing.

In UTF-8 encoding, this happens to be the codepoint for `U+00A0`.

Does `\x{00A0}` work? This should be the representation for `\xc2\xa0`.

Answer (score 1):

I did not work this variant `~\x{c2a0}~siu`.

Varian `\x{00A0}` works. I have not tried the second option and here is the result:

I tried to convert it to hex and replace no-break space `0xC2 0xA0 (c2a0)` to space `0x20 (20)`.

Code:

```
$hex = bin2hex($item);
$_item = str_replace('c2a0', '20', $hex);
$item = hex2bin($_item);
```

Answer (score 0):

/\x{00A0}/, /\xC2\xA0/ and $clean_hex2bin-str_replace-bin2hex worked and didn't work. If I printed it out to the screen, it's all good, but if I tried to save it to a file, the file would be blank!

I ended up using iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $str);