# Remove spaces from username while user login in php

Tags: php

I am trying to remove spaces from username while user logged in. for example if they have username like `TEST             BHA`  (there is space between TEST AND BHA)i want that username should be TESTBHA without space and it has to take lowercase while user logged in itself.

I have found some solutions but those are not working in my condition. Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue..

Here is my username:

```
 if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

        global $DB;

         $username = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['username']);
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM {user}  where username = ?";

        if ($user = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, array($username))) {
            //echo $user->password;
            //exit;
            if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
                if ($password != 'changeme'){
                  if ($user->trackforums == 1) {
                    complete_user_login($user);
                    \core\session\manager::apply_concurrent_login_limit($user->id, session_id());
                    $userauth = get_auth_plugin($USER->auth);

                    $DB->set_field('user', 'firstaccess', date('YmdHis'), array('id' => $user->id));
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;
                    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user->firstname;
                    $_SESSION['idnumber'] = $user->idnumber;
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id;
                    $_SESSION['clientid'] = $user->clientid;
                    $_SESSION['maildigest'] = $user->maildigest;
                    $_SESSION['skype'] = $user->skype;
                    $_SESSION['can_access'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['mnethostid'] = 1;
                    $_SESSION['confirmed'] = 1;

                    if (!empty($_POST["remember"])) {
                        setcookie("member_login", $_POST["username"], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                        setcookie("password", $_POST["password"], time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
                    } else {
                        if (isset($_COOKIE["member_login"])) {
                            setcookie("member_login", "");
                        }
                        if (isset($_COOKIE["password"])) {
                            setcookie("password", "");
                        }
                    }

                    if ($user->idnumber == '3')
                        header('location:course.php');
                    elseif ($user->idnumber == '2')
                        header('location:course.php');
                    else
                        header('location:course.php');
                }

                else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong> Sorry, User has been Deactivated. Contact Administrator</strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
                else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-primary">
                        <strong>Please change your password! By clicking this link <a style="color:red" href="forgot-password.php">Click Here</a></strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            } else {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong> Sorry, wrong password.</strong>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong> Sorry, wrong username.</strong>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To strip whitespaces inside a variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279774/to-strip-whitespaces-inside-a-variable-in-php)

Comment: i have tried this $str=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);  but its not working in my case

Comment: Did you try the obvious thing? https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Comment: could you try to `html_entity_decode($string);` before the replace. this space could be an nbsp

Comment: may you use the long regex in the duplicate I linked. perhaps the "space" is not a space but one of the white char.

Comment: Check the second answer down in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837682/non-breaking-utf-8-0xc2a0-space-and-preg-replace-strange-behaviour/12838189#12838189  one of those should get it for you

Comment: my problem is in if condition mainly as morgan told

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$username = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['username']);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
<?php 
$no_spaces = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['username']);
```

Comment: Its working just you have mistake somewhere, please send more code

Comment: i have updated my question i think problem is coming from if condition

Comment: The problem is in select you can try to echo your SQL query and try to execute it in phpmyadmin or console in this case you can try to edit your query in right way

Answer (score 1):

just use the str_replace function.

Example: $username = str_replace(" ", "", $_POST['username']);

It takes three arguments first is what to search for second is what to replace with and the third in what string you are searching for

Comment: Also don't forget to check if the super global is set with the isset() function or if you are using php 7 use the new isset operator. $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';