# Encoding issue when writing to text file, with Python

Tags: python, encoding

I'm writing a program to 'manually' arrange a csv file to be proper JSON syntax, using a short Python script.  From the input file I use `readlines()` to format the file as a list of rows, which I manipulate and concenate into a single string, which is then outputted into a separate .txt file.  The output, however, contains gibberish instead of Hebrew characters that were present in the input file, and the output is double-spaced, horizontally (a whitespace character is added in between each character).  As far as I can understand, the problem has to do with the encoding, but I haven't been able to figure out what.  When I detect the encoding of the input and output files (using `.encoding` attribute), they both return `None`, which means they use the system default.  Technical details: Python 2.7, Windows 7.

While there are a number of questions out there on this topic, I didn't find a direct answer to my problem. 
Detecting the system defaults won't help me in this case, because I need the program to be portable.

Here's the code:

```
def txt_to_JSON(csv_list):
    ...some manipulation of the list...
    return JSON_string
file_name = "input_file.txt"
my_file = open(file_name)
# make each line of input file a value in a list
lines = my_file.readlines()
# break up each line into a list such that each 'column' is a value in that list 
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    lines[i] = lines[i].split("\t")
J_string = txt_to_JSON(lines)
json_file = open("output_file.txt", "w+")
json_file.write(jstring)
json_file.close()
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when working with files in Python, it's best to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4).

Comment: Do you know what's the encoding of the input file?

Comment: @PauloBu He's reading Hebrew characters, but he's using ASCII in his program. This is most likely the problem.

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: In general, Python assumes ASCII, you have to specify the input encoding and output encoding when you're working with files encoded in some other encoding. (That sound a little funny :D)

Comment: @PauloBu: I don't know the input encoding, and as I noted (perhaps my edit came after your comment), I need it to be portable.

Comment: If I `print` the strings I'm working with, it comes out as Unicode. That is, it's already encoded, but I don't know the encoding.  If it's a matter of detecting the encoding, I understand that's a tricky and uncertain business, particularly since this program could be used on various platforms, etc...

Comment: Open the input file with `notepad`, chose Save As..., in the bottom of the pop-up window where the encoding is, choose UTF-8, save the file. Now you know your input file is utf8 (it should keep the hebrews characters intact) then try to run all the process again with that input. In case it doesn't work, please, add a brief example of the input file to try to parse it here and see if I can. I also have windows/python2.7

Comment: @PauloBu Again, I want this to work on any system. As well the directions I was given for doing the testwork on the program was to use a file saved as unicode, not UTF-8.

Comment: @jeg622 Unicode is a superset encoding. UTF-8 is an implementation of that encoding which is the most standardized. Python's unicode's string internally use utf-8. That's why I'm pointing to you to save the file in utf-8. In order to get this working in all systems, you have to get it working in one at least. We will write the code with no system specifics instructions, but first we have to see what's the problem.

Comment: @PauloBu If I save the input file as UTF-8, it works perfectly!  However, I was instructed to use a file saved as unicode.  I will question my team leader about that instruction and get back to you.

Comment: I'm glad. If you want to have some background to explain to your leader these links will be very helpful, specially the first: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/whats-the-difference-between-unicode-and-utf8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data needs to be encoded to be stored on disk. If you don't know the encoding, the best you can do is guess. There's a library for that: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

I highly recommend Ned Batchelder's presentation 
http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html 
for details.

There's an explanation about the use of "unicode" as an encoding on windows: [What's the difference between Unicode and UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951722/whats-the-difference-between-unicode-and-utf8)

TLDR: 
Microsoft uses UTF16 as encoding for unicode strings, but decided to call it "unicode" as they also use it internally.

Even if Python2 is a bit lenient as to string/unicode conversions, you should get used to always decode on input and encode on output.

In your case

```
filename = 'where your data lives'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
   encoded_data = f.read()
decoded_data = encoded_data.decode("UTF16")

# do stuff, resulting in result (all on unicode strings)
result = text_to_json(decoded_data)

encoded_result = result.encode("UTF-16")  #really, just using UTF8 for everything makes things a lot easier
outfile = 'where your data goes'
with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encoded_result)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  When I do this, however, the output file (created by `f.write()`) is still encoded as ANSI, so I get UnicodeEncodeError when it gets to the Hebrew characters. And btw, utf_16 is the proper notation.

Comment: Following your link, I changed the encoding from 'utf_16' to 'utf_16_le', and got a similar error, just relating to very beginning of the file rather than the non-ascii characters.

Comment: what program do you use to open the output file?

Comment: I use notepad. How would this affect the encoding?

Comment: the program has to decode the file to interpret what's in it. Can you put both files, or similar files with nonsense original text, someplace? I'd like to take a look

Comment: After some additional playing around (just in order to get a better understanding of what was going on), I reached additional conclusions: 1. Saving the file as 'unicode' and using `codecs.open()` with `utf_16` or `utf_16_le` as encoding produced a result similar to saving as 'utf-8' and opening it with `open()`, the sole difference being that when I saved it as 'unicode' the output file did not have any line breaks 2. Using `codecs.open()` is fundamentally different from `str.encode()`, but I don't really understand why.

Comment: For the record, [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-oE2XIgVJv2bmhkREJkU0pMQ0U/edit?usp=sharing) is the input file. The gibberish file can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-oE2XIgVJv2QkVTRWkxTTlCNDg/edit?usp=sharing), although on my computer the gibberish looked different, and the whole file was double-spaced. The correct file looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-oE2XIgVJv2YmtaVDdObzhDWE0/edit?usp=sharing).  For some reason all the tabs disappeared when I uploaded the files to Drive.

Comment: `codecs.open` using an encoding decodes data from the file while reading and encodes it while writing. So inside your code you only have unicode strings. 

it's equivalent to `f = open('filename', 'r+'); s = f.read().decode(encoding)` and later `f.write(s.encode(encoding))` so u"asdf".encode is only half the functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Python to use the Unicode character encoding to decode the Hebrew characters.
Here's a link to how you can read Unicode characters in Python: [Character reading from file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147741/character-reading-from-file-in-python)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find a solution there.  I tried using the `codecs` module, but nothing changed in the output.