# Windows-1252 Encoding in StreamWriter return ANSI encoded file

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I try to encode a string in Windows-1252 with a StreamWriter. The input string (dataString) is encode in UTF8.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\data.txt", true, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
sw.Write(dataString);
sw.Close();
```

When I open the file in Notepad++ I get a ANSI file. I need a Windows-1252 encoded file.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: How you you recognize it's ANSI rather than Windows-1252? Neither has the BOM header.

Comment: At the bottom of Notepad++ it show ANSI not Windows-1252

Comment: That's what I thought. See shf301's answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file is Windows-1252 encoded.  There is no data in the file of a non-Unicode to indicate how the file is encoded.  In this case ANSI just means not Unicode.  If you where to encode the as Russian/Windows-1251 and open it in Notepad++, Notepad++ would display it as ANSI as well.

See [Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI format differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences) for more info.