# php mysql .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

i am creating a website that handle a profile page and i need to get the username from the URL until this point all work fine but i am having a problem with using the **.htaccess** and i do not know how to fix this error 
this is my first time to use the .htaccess
i am using the WAMP package 
 and the browser give me this error  after i add the .htaccess file and it hide the folder that contain it.

**Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.**
this is a part of the profile.php

## profile.php

```
  // updatede for using the GET methode for ge the data nedded from the url 
    if(isset($_GET['u']))
    {
          $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['u']);
          if(ctype_alnum($username))
         {


          //check user exist
             $check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, first_name FROM user WHERE user_name = '$username' ")or die(mysql_error());
             if (mysql_num_rows($check)==1) 
             {
               $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
               $username = $get['user_name']; 
               $fname = $get['first_name'];
             }
             else
             {
                echo "<h2>User does not Exist!!</h2>";
                exit();  
             }
          }
       }

        echo "$username";
?>
```

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1



RewriteRule^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1
```

Comment: Did you try adding whitespaces between `RewriteRule` and your rewrite rules?

Comment: I'm using my mobile browser so it's hard to tell, but I think your formatting is wrong there should be a space after rewriterule before the ^

Comment: yes their is a space between these 2 lines                             
RewriteRule^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1



RewriteRule^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1

Comment: @user2172837 That's not what you are being asked; there's a big difference between this: `RewriteRule^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1` and this: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1` (the last example having a whitespace after `RewriteRule`).

Comment: @ – Repox sir this the first time i use the .htaccess i do not understand what you are saying can you explain

Comment: I did - two times! You need to have a space between `RewriteRule` and `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1` in your .htaccess file. A space - the long button in the bottom of your keyboard.

Comment: off topic, but it's worth knowing that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated. If at all possible, I recommend switching to the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: you probably need a rewritecond on the {REQUEST_URI}

Comment: @  Repox  i have a space between RewriteRule and ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1  but still having error and the folder is still hiding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not save your `.htaccess` file in UTF8 charcter encoding. save it in ANSI

Comment: why would you do such a thing, i've always used utf-8 without any problem

Comment: @Sebas I had experience about it. perhaps some apache servers have problem with it.

Comment: mmm so how to solve this is that any tutorial that i  use it ?? be cause until now i did not get success with this error

Comment: @user2172837, just save it in ANSI mode.hope this solve your problem.
you can use windows `Notepad` and then save as, then select ANSI

Comment: @Amir still the same error .. does the place of the file must be in some  specific path or no  because the folder that hold .htaccess it is hidding and i can not choose it

Comment: @user2172837, it usually should be in root

Comment: it is in the root folder and this folder and not appear as it is hide

Comment: thank you AMIR  you saved me but it do not make any sense  what is the difference between the type of encoding ??

Comment: @user2172837, There is some explanation about difference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences
Also you can google it...some hiding characters cause server to error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that profile.php has no errors. Try to delete your last line of the .htaccess file. Also add a space between Rewriterule and '^'.
Adding whitespace to the regex has nothing do to with this, because of the ctype_alnum() function. This only permits alphabetic characters.

Just copy and pase this to your .htaccess file and (ofcourse) delete the previous lines:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1

Comment: i did as you said but the error still the same and the folder still not appearing