# Turbo Grep - find special characters in UTF-8 file

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, grep

I am running Windows 7 and (have to) use Turbo Grep (Borland something) to search in a file.
I have 2 version of this file, one encoded in UTF-8 and one in ANSI.

If I run the following grep on the ANSI file, I get the expected results, but I get no results with the same statement on the UTF-8 file:

```
grep -ni "[äöü]" myfile.txt
```

[-n for line numbers, -i for ignoring cases]

The Turbo Grep Version is :

```
Turbo GREP 5.6 Copyright (c) 1992-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Syntax:  GREP [-rlcnvidzewoqhu] searchstring file[s] or @filelist
         GREP ? for help
```

Help for this command lists:

`Options are one or more option characters preceded by "-", and optionally
    followed by "+" (turn option on), or "-" (turn it off).  The default is "+".
       -r+  Regular expression search       -l-  File names only 
       -c-  match Count only                -n-  Line numbers 
   -v-  Non-matching lines only         -i-  Ignore case 
   -d-  Search subdirectories           -z-  Verbose 
   -e   Next argument is searchstring   -w-  Word search 
   -o-  UNIX output format                   Default set: [0-9A-Z_]
   -q-  Quiet: supress normal output 
   -h-  Supress display of filename 
   -u xxx Create a copy of grep named 'xxx' with current options set as default`

A regular expression is one or more occurrences of:  One or more characters 
optionally enclosed in quotes.  The following symbols are treated specially:
      ^  start of line             $  end of line 
      .  any character             \ quote next character 
      *  match zero or more        +  match one or more 
      [aeiou0-9]   match a, e, i, o, u, and 0 thru 9 ; 
      [^aeiou0-9]  match anything but a, e, i, o, u, and 0 thru 9

Is there a problem with the encoding of these charactes in UTF-8? Might there be a problem with Turbo Grep and UTF-8?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are a different w7 use UTF-16 little endian not UTF-8, UTF-8 is used in unix, linux and plan 9 for cite a few OS.

Jon Skeet explain:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/4535278)

> ANSI: There's no one fixed ANSI encoding - there are lots of them. Usually when people say "ANSI" they mean "the default code page for my system" which is obtained via Encoding.Default, and is often Windows-1252
>
> UTF-8: Variable length encoding, 1-4 bytes covers every current character. ASCII values are encoded as ASCII.

UTF-16 is more similar to ANSI so for this reason with ANSI work well.

if you use only ascii  both encodings are usable, but with special characters  as ä ö ü etc you need use UTF-16 in windows and UTF-8 in the others