# Marshaling managed string to char pointer c#

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unmanaged

I am playing around with the Marshal class in C# and am slightly confused by the result of this operation:

```
string someVal = "Hello There";
IntPtr ptS = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(someVal);
char* ptsPt = (char*)ptS.ToPointer();
```

After looking at ptsPt[0] in the immediate window it contains this value: '效'

I am guessing it has something to do with the `StringToHGlobalAnsi`Method treating the managed chars as 8 bit values, but when they really they are 16 bit. But I cannot quite understand why this is happening.

I know I can get around this issue by changing it  to `StringToHGlobalUni`. But I don't understand why this is!

Cheers

Comment: [Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI format differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences)

Comment: Try using `byte* ptS` and `(char)(ptS[0])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because in C#, `char` is a 16-bit wide type. `StringToHGlobalAnsi` *converts* the string to ANSI, that is 1 byte per character. Then you look at `ptsPt[0]`, which is interpreted to contain both of the first two ANSI characters.

Here's what the original string look like in memory:

```
00 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 ...
```

This is because C# strings are stored in UTF-16, and the above is UTF-16 for "Hello There".

After the call to `StringToHGlobalAnsi`, a new piece of memory is allocated, containing these bytes:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 ...
```

(and incidentally, this means you should free it with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` when you're done).

Then, when you get a `char*` to this, the first `char` pointed to comprises the bytes `48 65`, which due to little endianness really means `0x6548`, which [stands for the character 效](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x6548/index.html).

Comment: Great answer, cheers! I was getting 25928, 效 - which I guess is the decimal representation of the hex value 0x6548. Just a quick question about how the string looks in memory though - why is do we need to have that additional byte on c# managed chars? 48 00 is 'H'. Is it so we can store additional characters - like the asian symbol we saw early (sorry I don't know what language it's from!)

Comment: @William as a first approximation, yes, the reason is to expand the number of characters that can be represented by a single `char` value. Ultimately though it's a leftover from those times when it was thought that 65536 different characters will be enough for everything (Unicode v1.*).