# Why does VBS not read this text file correctly?

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code to read a text file:

```
Option Explicit 
Dim InputFile 
Dim FSO, oFile 
Dim strData 

InputFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\CloudCare\ClientVersion.txt" 
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile) 
strData = oFile.ReadAll 
oFile.Close 
msgbox strData
```

The contents of ClientVersion.txt is:

```
CLIENT_VERSION_STRING   _T("3.5.2") //
```

When I run the VBS code, I get back this:

[image: VBS txt file read]

If I create a new text file with the same content in the same location, it works fine. Is there a reason why VBS is unable to read this simple text file? I couldn't see any issues with permissions on the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ÿþ` is the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark) of a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Little Endian encoded file. UTF-16 (unlike ASCII/ANSI) uses two bytes for a character instead of just one. However, the `OpenTextFile` method reads files as ASCII files by default, so each 2-byte character gets interpreted as two separate characters.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> object.OpenTextFile(filename[, iomode[, create[, format]]])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>   […]
>   *format*
>       Optional. One of three **Tristate** values used to indicate the format of the opened file (**TristateTrue** = -1 to open the file as Unicode, **TristateFalse** = 0 to open the file as ASCII, **TristateUseDefault** = -2 to open the file as the system default). ***If omitted, the file is opened as ASCII.***

Specify the proper encoding when reading the file and the problem will disappear:

```
Set oFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile, 1, False, -1)
```

Comment: Wow, you not remember [answering this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36152812/692942)?