# Different Number of Character in Java Android InputStream and C++ ifstream

Tags: java, android, c++, inputstream, ifstream

So, I am developing android application that read JSON text file containing some data. I have a 300 kb (307,312 bytes) JSON in a text file ([here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B74cKCXjF_5LQ1NYZkZkRE5GZzg)). I also develop desktop application (cpp) to generate and loading (and parsing) the JSON text file.

When I try to open and read it using ifstream in c++, I get the string length correctly (307,312). I even succesfully parse it.

Here is my code in C++:

```
std::string json = "";
std::string line;
std::ifstream myfile(textfile.txt);

if(myfile.is_open()){
    while(std::getline(myfile, line)){
        json += line;
        json.push_back('\n');
    }
    json.pop_back(); // pop back the last '\n'
    myfile.close();
}else{
    std::cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

In my android application, I put my JSON text file in res/raw folder. When I try to open and read using InputStream, the length of the string only 291,896. And I can't parse it (I parse it using jni with the same c++ code, maybe it is not important).

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(b);
in_str = new String(b);
```

UPDATE:

I also have try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5675934/2417257) way.

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = reader.readLine();
while(line != null){
    in_str += line;
    in_str += '\n';
    line = reader.readLine();
}
if (in_str != null && in_str.length() > 0) {
    in_str = in_str.substring(0, in_str.length()-1);
}
```

Even, I tried moving it from res/raw folder to assets folder in java android project. And of course I change the `InputStream` line to `InputStream is = getAssets().open("textfile.txt")`. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution. It is the **ASCII** and **UTF-8** problem.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/2417257):

- **UTF-8** Variable length encoding, 1-4 bytes per code point. ASCII values are encoded as ASCII using 1 byte.
- **ASCII** Single byte encoding

My filesize is 307,312 bytes and basically I need to take the character each byte. So, I should need to encode the file as ASCII.

When I am using **C++ `ifstream`**, the string size is 307,312. (same as of the number character if it is using **ASCII** encoding)

Meanwhile, when I am using **Java `InputStream`**, the string size is 291,896. I assume that it happens because of the reader is using **UTF-8** encoding instead.

So, how to use get **ASCII** encoding in **Java**?

Through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716521/2417257) thread and [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42) article, we can use `InputStreamReader` in Java and set it to **ASCII**. Here is my complete code:

```
String in_str = "";
try{
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "ASCII"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        in_str += line;
        in_str += '\n';
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    if (in_str != null && in_str.length() > 0) {
        in_str = in_str.substring(0, in_str.length()-1);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you have the same problem, hope this helps. Cheers.