# .NET StreamReader encoding behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, unicode-string

I am trying to understand the unicode encoding behaviour and came across the following,

I am writing to a file a string using Encoding.Unicode using

```
StreamWriter(fileName,false, Encoding.Unicode);
```

I am reading from the same file but use ASCII intentionally.

```
 StreamReader(fileName,false, Encoding.ASCII);
```

When I read the string using ReadLine to my surprise it is giving back the same unicode string.

I expected the string to contain ? or other characters with double the length of the original string.

What is happening here?

Code Snippet

```
string test= "سشصضطظع";//some random arabic set
StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fileName,false, Encoding.UTF8);
s.Write(input);
s.Flush();
s.Close();
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(fileName, encoding);
string ss  = s.ReadLine();
s.Close();
//In string ss I expect to be a ascii with Double the length of test
```

If I call StreamReader s = new StreamReader(fileName, encoding, false);
then it gives the expected result.`

Thanks

Comment: The input is already unicode arabic characters copied from Character map. I found that it is due to the parameter that I am passing. Thanks

Comment: Please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/2846483). You will note that `Unicode` actually isn't an encoding while `ASCII` is.

Comment: @dymanoid in .NET, "Encoding.Unicode" _is_ an encoding, namely [UTF-16 little-endian](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx). Not saying I agree with the naming.

Comment: @HAN Please write your answer in an answer post and remove it from the question.

Comment: "When I read the string using ReadLine to my surprise it is giving back the same unicode string." I don't believe it really is (unless it's empty). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure where my answer is gone. The code is updated on the question. The parameter detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks is responsible for the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks should be set to false when creating StreamReader object.