# CString resources displaying as ANSI

Tags: c++, string, winapi, resources

**Problem**

I have some resource files I've translated into a couple of languages and I noticed that some characters aren't being displayed correctly in my UI.

For example: `Versión:` is displaying as `VersiÃ³n:`.  I've ensured that I have the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` directives which, from everything I've read, should work as expected. What could be causing this?

**Code**

The code that's being called (and I did verify it's reaching this method):

```
static HINSTANCE _languageDll = NULL; //Setup in another function call

CString GetLangString(int resourceId)
{
    CString langString;

    langString.LoadString(_languageDll, resourceId);

    return langString;
}
```

Inspecting `langString` I can see it's loading `VersiÃ³n:`

To see if it was a display issue I tried something similar to the following and it displayed correctly:

```
return CString("Versión:");
```

Looking through the code I noticed there's a define called `LoadString` in *WinUser.h* which switches between `LoadStringW` and `LoadStringA` based on the `UNICODE` directive. After some Google-fu I tried the following with no luck:

```
CString GetLangString(int resourceId)
{
    WCHAR buffer[256];

    LoadString(_languageDll, resourceId, buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(WCHAR));

    return CString(buffer);
}
```

I didn't let it return, looking at the debugger I could see it again loaded `VersiÃ³n:`.

I'm at a total loss as to why this is happening. Could it be something with the resource files? I'm just diving into C++ so my skills could be better (AKA I'm a noob) so any help on this would be really appreciated.

Note: I'm taking over a project built by someone else so the reasoning behind why certain functionality is used is unknown to me.

**Edit 1**

The string in the original RC file is as follows:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_STRING703           "Version: %d.%d.%d.%d"
END
```

And in the translated RC file:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_STRING703           "Versión: %d.%d.%d.%d"
END
```

Comment: Famous complaints in the R&D department of my company: _"Schei� Encoding!"_ :-D Sorry please, I couldn't resist.

Comment: What does the string definition look like in the .rc file?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I updated the question with a snippet of what the original and translated RC files look like

Comment: Has the translated .rc file been saved with a BOM at the start (`FFFE`)? If you change the string to `L"Versi\x00f3n: %d.%d.%d.%d"` (the `L` is important) does it work?

Comment: @JonathanPotter There is no BOM at the start of the translated files, does that need to be there? Putting the `L` didn't have any effect (although there's no BOM so I could see that might be the cause)

Comment: I ended up changing the encoding on the RC file (through NP++) to ANSI and now it works. Is the issue the original RC files had the wrong encoding? Is ANSI right?

Comment: You should probably save it as a UTF-16 file. When you added the L did you also add the \x00f3 ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'll give that a try, my build is broken right now so Ican't test these out. When I added the `L` I didn't have `\x00f3`, I'll give that a try as well. Do you know what the cause is? Is it because the resource has to be converted to Unicode and when it's in UTF-8 without the BOM it gets treated as ANSI?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I was finally able to get it working and using the `L` prefix with UTF-16 worked as you suggested. If you want to create an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you save the resource file utf-16 format, not ANSI. 
And you can reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700187/unicode-utf-ascii-ansi-format-differences) to learn about the format differences.