# Python CSV DictReader with UTF-8 data

Tags: python, unicode, csv

AFAIK, the Python (v2.6) csv module can't handle unicode data by default, correct? In the Python docs there's an [example](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) on how to read from a UTF-8 encoded file. But this example only returns the CSV rows as a list.
I'd like to access the row columns by name as it is done by `csv.DictReader` but with UTF-8 encoded CSV input file.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in an efficient way? I will have to process CSV files in 100's of MByte in size.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I came up with an answer myself:

```
def UnicodeDictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield {unicode(key, 'utf-8'):unicode(value, 'utf-8') for key, value in row.iteritems()}
```

<sub>*Note: This has been updated so keys are decoded per the suggestion in the comments*</sub>

Comment: choose it as the answer then :)

Comment: ok, didn't know I can do that :) I will wait some time to see if someone knows a better way, then accept it.

Comment: -1 This doesn't decode the dictionary keys in the first row of the file.

Comment: You can actually save a few characters by removing the list comprehension brackets inside the dict constructor. That makes it a generator, and inside function calls w/ one argument the parentheses of generators are optional. :-P

Comment: Be aware that it doesn't handle csv.DictReader restkey flag functionality

Comment: No need to apologize for answering your own question. That's one of the intended uses of stackoverflow. Now everyone else can share what you taught yourself!

Comment: As John Machin mentioned, this will not decode the keys; the yield line should be: yield {unicode(key, 'utf-8'):unicode(value, 'utf-8') for key, value in row.iteritems()}

Answer (score 39):

For me, the key was not in manipulating the csv DictReader args, but the file opener itself. This did the trick:

```
with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

No special class required. Now I can open files either with or without BOM without crashing.

Comment: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @ATX Odd - I wonder if you were on python2 rather than 3?

Comment: Yes indeed it was p2

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use the [2.6 version of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/csv.html). It can change for each release. It says clearly that it doesn't support Unicode but it does support UTF-8. [Technically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode), these are not the same thing. As the docs say:

> The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode, but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.

The example below (from the docs) shows how to create two functions that correctly read text as UTF-8 as CSV. You should know that `csv.reader()` always returns a DictReader object.

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
```

Comment: `csv.reader()` does not return a DictReader object when I test it. Are you sure about that? Also the yield statement in your example just returns a list with the values only and not a dict.

Comment: I guess you're right about the DictReader. I changed the example to invoke `csv.DictReader` instead of `csv.reader`. Note that other than this difference, this is directly out of the documentation.

Comment: I think your reader still does not return a dict but just a list of the row values (see the yield statement). But thanks for your answer, anyway, after re-reading the documentation that you mentioned, I came up with a solution myself (finally :))

Comment: @LMatter do you mind sharing that solution you found?

Answer (score 1):

A classed based approach to @LMatter answer, with this approach you still get all the benefits of DictReader such as getting the fieldnames and getting the line number plus it handles UTF-8

```
import csv

class UnicodeDictReader(csv.DictReader, object):

    def next(self):
        row = super(UnicodeDictReader, self).next()
        return {unicode(key, 'utf-8'): unicode(value, 'utf-8') for key, value in row.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's easy with the [unicodecsv](https://pypi.org/project/unicodecsv/) package.

```py
# pip install unicodecsv
import unicodecsv as csv

with open('your_file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`csvw` package](https://github.com/cldf/csvw/) has other functionality as well (for metadata-enriched CSV for the Web), but it defines a `UnicodeDictReader` class wrapping around its `UnicodeReader` class, which at its core does exactly that:

```
class UnicodeReader(Iterator):
    """Read Unicode data from a csv file."""
    […]

    def _next_row(self):
        self.lineno += 1
        return [
            s if isinstance(s, text_type) else s.decode(self._reader_encoding)
            for s in next(self.reader)]
```

It did catch me off a few times, but `csvw.UnicodeDictReader` *really, really* needs to be used in a `with` block and breaks otherwise. Other than that, the module is nicely generic and compatible with both py2 and py3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't have the `DictWriter` methods, so here is the updated class:

```
class DictUnicodeWriter(object):

    def __init__(self, f, fieldnames, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        self.fieldnames = fieldnames    # list of keys for the dict
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.DictWriter(self.queue, fieldnames, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow({k: v.encode("utf-8") for k, v in row.items()})
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

    def writeheader(self):
        header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
        self.writerow(header)
```