# python module like csv-DictReader with full utf8 support

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I need import data from a csv in my project and i need a object like DictReader, but with full utf8 supports, anyone knows a module or app with this?

Comment: Your file appears to be encoded in `cp1252`, not `UTF-8` (see my answer) ... please respond.

Comment: Your right, the encoding wasn't utf8, but when i try your code, i got an error about keys because the keys are the second data row, not the first.

Comment: The csv DictReader expects the keys to be the FIRST row in the file. Your "sampleresults.csv" file on `dropbox` has the keys in the FIRST row. If you have another file with junk in the first row, and keys in the second row, of course the outcome would be sub-optimal. Please show (0) What version of Python you are using, on what platform (1) what code you used to call my code, and (2) EXACTLY what the "error about keys" was. See also my updated answer.

Comment: nevermind, i change my code, i think the error was iterate twice on file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your data is NOT encoded in UTF-8. It is (mostly) encoded in cp1252**. The data appears to include Spanish names. The most prevalent non-ASCII character is '\xd1` (i.e. Latin capital letter N with tilde) -- this is the character that caused the exception.

One of the non-ASCII characters in the file is '\x8d'. It is NOT in cp1252. It appears where the letter A should appear in the name VASQUEZ. Of the others, '\x94' (curly double quote in cp1252) appears in the middle of a name. The remaining ones may also represent errors.

I suggest that you run this little code fragment to print lines with suspicious characters in them:

```
for lino, line in enumerate(open('sampleresults.csv')):
    if any(c in line for c in '\x8d\x94\xc1\xcf\xd3'): print "%d %r\n" % (lino+1, line)
```

and fix up the data.

Then you need a csv DictReader with **full** and **generalised** decoding support. Full means decoding the fieldnames aka dict keys as well as the data. Generalised means no hardcoding of the encoding.

import csv

```
def UnicodeDictReader(str_data, encoding, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(str_data, **kwargs)
    # Decode the keys once
    keymap = dict((k, k.decode(encoding)) for k in csv_reader.fieldnames)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield dict((keymap[k], v.decode(encoding)) for k, v in row.iteritems())

dozedata = ['\xd1,\xff', '\xd2,\xfe', '3,4']
print list(UnicodeDictReader(dozedata, 'cp1252'))
```

Output:

```
[{u'\xd1': u'\xd2', u'\xff': u'\xfe'}, {u'\xd1': u'3', u'\xff': u'4'}]
```

and here is what you get with your sample file (first data row only, Python 2.7.1, Windows 7):

```
>>> import csv
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> def UnicodeDictReader(str_data, encoding, **kwargs):
...     csv_reader = csv.DictReader(str_data, **kwargs)
...     # Decode the keys once
...     keymap = dict((k, k.decode(encoding)) for k in csv_reader.fieldnames)
...     for row in csv_reader:
...         yield dict((keymap[k], v.decode(encoding)) for k, v in row.iteritems())
...
>>> f = open('sampleresults.csv', 'rb')
>>> drdr = UnicodeDictReader(f, 'cp1252')
>>> pp(drdr.next())
{u'APELLIDO': u'=== family names redacted ===',
 u'CATEGORIA': u'ABIERTA',
 u'CEDULA': u'10000640',
 u'DELAY': u' 0:20',
 u'EDAD': u'25',
 u'EMAIL': u'mimail640',
 u'NO.': u'640',
 u'NOMBRE': u'=== given names redacted ===',
 u'POSICION CATEGORIA': u'1',
 u'POSICION CATEGORIA EN KM.5': u'11',
 u'POSICION GENERAL CHIP': u'1',
 u'POSICION GENERAL EN KM.5': u'34',
 u'POSICION GENERAL GUN': u'1',
 u'POSICION GENERO': u'1',
 u'PRIMEROS 5KM.': u'0:32:55',
 u'PROMEDIO/KM.': u' 5:44',
 u'SEGUNDOS KM.': u'0:24:05',
 u'SEX': u'M',
 u'TIEMPO CHIP': u'0:56:59',
 u'TIEMPO GUN': u'0:57:19'}
>>>
```

Comment: I have a CSV saved from Excel. I tried encodings: cp1252 (Windows), utf8. And I use your example of `UnicodeDictReader` to read the data in CSV as `dict`. After the data is parsed, I put it into `Jinja2` template which uses only `utf8`. And I found that Arabic text is decoded wrong because I get only question marks in the rendered template instead Arabic. I use [this](http://pastebin.com/Wtij70Vi) code.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004687/python-csv-dictreader-with-utf-8-data/5005573#5005573) said :

```
def UnicodeDictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield dict([(key, unicode(value, 'utf-8')) for key, value in row.iteritems()])
```

You can see below my example code. I'm using your csv file (see comments).

```
import csv

def UnicodeDictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(utf8_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield dict([(key, unicode(value, 'utf-8')) for key, value in row.iteritems()])

f = open('sampleresults.csv', 'r')
a = UnicodeDictReader(f)
for i in a:
    if i['NOMBRE'] == 'GUIDO ALEJANDRO':
        print i['APELLIDO']
```

Ouput:

```
MUÑOZ RENGIFO
```

You can see that the 'Ñ' is correctly encoded.

Comment: doesn't works, i got this: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 2: invalid continuation byte in the yield line

Comment: Can you provide your csv file ?

Comment: HELLO HELLO this can't work -- his file is definitely NOT encoded in UTF-8 (see my answer); how do you explain the error message that he got?

Comment: -1 **AND** like the answer that you copied, it doesn't decode the keys (fieldnames) in the first row of the file.