# Encoding a csvreader

Tags: python, csv

I have a latin1 encoded file. How would I do the equivalent of the following with `csv`?

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Comment: Do you mean `encoding='latin-1'`? Sorry, I'm not seeing the difficulty...

Comment: @Basic the `csv`.`DictReader` doesn't allow the setting of encoding as a parameter.

Comment: Ah, ok. You'll need to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5005573/156755)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it:

```
def Latin1ToUnicodeDictReader(latin1_data, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(latin1_data, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield {key: value.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8') if value else value for key, value in row.iteritems()}

reader = Latin1ToUnicodeDictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

Comment: This actually didn't work when I tried it. Also I think you mean `codes.open` ?