# Lock symbol in a layout

Tags: android, unicode, textview

I've been trying to put a [Lock Symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f512/index.htm) in the **`textview`** of an **`activity`**.
However what I have used from this website did not seem to work.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lockTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:text="\uD83D\uDD12"/>
```

**EDIT**

As you see from my example I had wanted to set the 'unicode' representation of the lock symbol as text in the 'TextView' in the xml. However, the only way to show the lock symbol was by setting it in code.

I am looking for a way to do this in the xml OR an explanation why this way acts different from setting it in code.

Comment: is your font supports that symbol?  The ascii not supports that symbol. https://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html

Comment: @Elango I've done something similar with a Checkmark (\u2713). I had expected the same format to work for the Lock symbol. But it did not.

Comment: pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126302/java-not-displaying-a-special-utf-symbol)

Comment: @Elango I had expected something similar to the pedestrian. So where can I check if my lock mark is allowed or not?

Comment: you could change your font, which one support that symbol.

Comment: Sure but I am just trying to understand why it works when setting from code and does not work when setting from the xml.

Comment: Maybe your xml layout file is not saved with Unicode encoding?

Comment: @BernoulliGate in that same xml I also use the Checkmark (\u2713). This does not seem to be the case :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add drawable by the following ways,

```
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
```

Also you can use with xml,

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_locText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img_lock"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/name"/>
```

Other than this, better you can also use image as background of textview

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_lock_background"
```

For programmatically : Try with below updated code,

Adding the Unicode character within java to the String in the XML file:

```
String str = "\uD83D\uDD12" + getContext().getString(R.string.your_string);
```

Comment: I do not want an image. I want the unicode representation to work.

Comment: Setting this character from code works. But I had wanted to set it from xml.