# Convert and correct corrupt UTF-8 text into ANSI?

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, character-encoding, ansi

I am not a professional developer, and am having a problem converting `Unicode text` to `ANSI` found in a legacy application that doesn't support `Unicode`.

Here's a sample of what a `Unicode`-encoded text looks like when displayed in that legacy application:

> Ã€ chaque journÃ©e des quatre jours de colloque, entre 250 et 500
>   personnes sont venues assister en continu aux discussions de cette
>   rencontre. Cette affluence, ainsi que la richesse et la variÃ©tÃ© des
>   discussions engagÃ©es lors de ces confÃ©rences, confirment la
>   nÃ©cessitÃ© d'un espace ouvert pour les pensÃ©es critiques dans le
>   monde francophone, Ã  l'universitÃ© et bien au-delÃ .

I notice the following things:

- All diacritic characters are encoded as C3 ("Ã") + a second byte
- The character "à" is wrongly encoded as C320 ("Ã ")
- Windows' CharacterMap application says that "é" is "U+00E9" while the document contains C3A9 instead.

I have a couple of questions:

1. Why the difference between the document and `CharacterMap`: Is the
   document encoded in something else than `Unicode`? For instance, why
   is `é` encoded as `C3A9`instead of `00E9`?
2. I use the following VB.Net code to convert the document from `Unicode` to `Ansi`: How can I replace all occurrences of `C320` with `à`?

   ```
   Dim Encw1252 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")
   Dim EncUTF8 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
   Dim Str As String
   Str = Encw1252.GetString(Encoding.Convert(EncUTF8, Encw1252, encoding.Default.GetBytes(Clipboard.GetText)))
   Clipboard.SetText(Str)
   ```

Comment: Thanks Kashish for the editing.

Comment: utf-8 and unicode are different. utf-8 can encode a character up to 4Bytes and unicode is 2Bytes. So if it is utf-8 some characters maybe 3 or 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks Valter. So the text is actually UTF-8, not Unicode.

Comment: Most probably. To be sure though, check the actual bytes. If you see a byte with value larger than E0, then it is utf-8. E0 <= character value <= EF the character is encoded with 3bytes and character value >= F0 then 4bytes

Comment: `C3A9` is the UTF-8 byte sequence to encode `U+00E9` Unicode code point. Unicode is a character set that maps human signs to abstract numeric *code points*. On the other hand, UTF-8 is a way to encode these *code points* into *byte sequences*. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode) for more about this topic.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the solution that worked as an answer, and accept it straight away (so that the question does not appear as unresolved anymore)

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> For others' benefit, problem solved using the following code:
>
> ```
> Dim Encw1252 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")
> Dim EncUTF8 As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
>
> Dim Str As String
> Str = Clipboard.GetText
> Str = Str.Replace("Ã ", "Ã ")
> Str = Encw1252.GetString(Encoding.Convert(EncUTF8, Encw1252, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Str)))
> Clipboard.SetText(Str)
> MessageBox.Show(Str)
> ```
>
> In the `Str.Replace(`) above, the second byte in the source is a space (20) while the second byte in the target is "No break space" (160).