# █ character string indexed in python

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, python-2.x

I'm trying to get the index of 'J' in a string that is similar to `myString = "███  ███ J ██"` so I use `myString.find('J')` but it returns a really high value and if I replace '█' by 'M' or another character of the alphabet I get a lower value.  I don't really understand what's the cause of that.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Because it isn't an ASCII character. If, for example, Python uses the common UTF8 encoding scheme for its internal strings, this character will be represented by *three* one-byte codes: `0xE2 0x96 0x88`.

Comment: Which python version are you using?  It could be an issue with unicode handling in python 2.x.

Comment: `lower value=-1` because except J there is no other alphabet

Comment: @Aereaux It is. If you declare it as a Unicode String, i.e. myString = u"███ ███ J ██", find works fine.

Comment: @Jongware and Aereaux have the correct answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing `myString = u"███ ███ J ██"`.  This will make it a Unicode string instead of the python 2.x default of an ASCII string.

If you are reading it from a file or a file-like object, instead of doing `file.read()`, do `file.read().encode('utf-8-sig')`.

Answer (score 2):

To check your encoding run: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding())'`

For Python 2.x the output is `ascii` and this is a default encoding for your programs. To use some non-ascii characters developers predicted a unicode() type. See for yourself. Just create a variable `myString = u"███ ███ J ██"` and follow on it `.find('J')` method. This `u` prefix says to interpreter that it deals with Unicode-encoded string. Then you can use this variable like if it was normal str.

I've used Unicode in some places where I should write UTF-8. For difference check [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode) if you want to.

Unicode is a default encoding in Python 3.x, so this problem does not occur.

Comment: and what about if my string from a file:
myFile = open("map/map1", "r")
myMap = (myFiler.read())

Comment: Use `myFile = open("map/map1", "r")` `myMap = (myFiler.read().encode('utf-8-sig'))`

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings of the console/ssh client you are using. Set it to be UTF-8.