# Why is it necessary to mark continuation bytes in UTF-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I've recently been reading up on the UTF-8 variable-width encoding, and I found it strange that UTF-8 specifies the first two bits of every continuation byte to be 10.

```
 Range           |  Encoding
-----------------+-----------------
     0 - 7f      |  0xxxxxx
    80 - 7ff     |  110xxxx 10xxxxxx
   800 - ffff    |  1110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
 10000 - 10ffff  |  11110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

I was playing around with other possible variable width encodings, and found that by using the following scheme, at most 3 bytes are necessary to store all of Unicode. If the first bit is a 1, then the character is encoded in at least one more byte (read until the first bit is a 0).

```
 Range           |  Encoding
-----------------+-----------------
     0 - 7f      |  0xxxxxx
    80 - 407f    |  1xxxxxx 0xxxxxxx
  4080 - 20407f  |  1xxxxxx 1xxxxxxx 0xxxxxxx
```

Are the continuation bits in UTF-8 really that important? The second encoding seems much more efficient.

Comment: The UTF-8 scheme allows you to recover the intended decoding from *any* code unit position.

Comment: Even with my encoding this is possible. From any arbitrary position, step back until you find an ending byte (with a 0), then the next byte is the start of the character.

Comment: Not really: If you point at a `0xxxxxx` byte, I can't tell whether that's a complete character or a corrupted ending of a multibyte sequence. (Assuming I can't go backward.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The UTF-8 is self-validating, fast on stepping forward, and easier to step backward.

*Self-validating:* Since the first byte in the sequence specifies the length, the next X bytes must fit `10xxxxxx`, or you have an invalid sequence. Seeing a `10xxxxxx` byte by itself is immediately recognizable as invalid.
Your suggested encoding has no validation built-in.

*Fast on step forward:* If you have to skip the character, you can immediately skip X bytes as determined by the first byte, without having to examine each intermediate byte.

*Easier to step backward:* If you have to read the bytes backwards, you can immediately recognize a continuation character by the `10xxxxxx`. You'll then be able to scan backwards past the `10xxxxxx` bytes for the `11xxxxxx` lead byte, without having to scan past the lead byte.

See [UTF-8 Invalid sequences and error handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_sequences_and_error_handling) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from ease of iteration as already mentioned: UTF-8 aims to be safe for ASCII-based (and other UTF-8-unaware) tools to process through such common manipulations as searching, concatenation, replacing, and escaping.

The advantages of ASCII-compatibilty for interop and security outweigh the costs of using an extra byte for characters U+0800 to U+407F.

> 80 - 407f    |  1xxxxxx 0xxxxxxx

So there were a few East Asian multibyte encodings that did it like that, with some unfortunate results which UTF-8 was specifically trying to avoid.

In this proposed scheme the continuation bytes now overlap with ASCII, and many ASCII characters have special meanings to different languages and tools. So if you want to say `¢` that's 0x80,0x27 and the second byte of that looks like a `"` to any tool that manipulates byte strings without support for, and knowledge that this data using, the proposed encoding.

Cue security holes in everything that combines user input into control flow. SQL injection in queries, HTML injection on web pages, command injection in shell scripts and so on.

(The East Asian multibyte encodings weren't quite as bad as this encoding here, as they didn't reuse the ASCII control codes as continuation bytes. As proposed, text using this encoding can't be stored in a C null-terminated string, for example. Still, Shift-JIS and friends caused a whole bunch of security holes and we are all very glad to be rid of them.)

Answer (score 3):

Using your proposed scheme, if you look at a byte encoded 0xxxxxxx, you can't tell whether that's a single byte unit 0x00..0x7F or the last byte of a multi-byte unit.  You have to scan backwards and look at the preceding byte to know (and you would have to check backwards two units to see whether this it the last byte of a 2 or 3 byte code point).  If you have a 1xxxxxxx byte, you can't tell whether it is the first byte of a multibyte unit or the middle byte.  Again, you'd have to scan backwards.

By contrast, the UTF-8 scheme allows you to tell for any non-continuation byte how many subsequent bytes are part of the code point.  For continuation bytes, you only have to scan backwards to the start byte.  You also get error checking; there are many invalid sequences in UTF-8 which is actually a benefit.  (The bytes 0xC0, 0xC1, 0xF5..0xFF cannot appear in valid UTF-8.)