# get unicode buffer bytes in c# returns '??????'

Tags: c#, unicode, byte, buffer

I have a function that gets data from buffer and converts them to string as  you can see :

```
public string GetParameters(byte[] buf)
{
    string result = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buf);
    return result;
}
```

Another application sends a `Farsi` string to buffer and my application should get this data, but my application's function returns this:

```
㨲께裙듘�����¯
```

Why ?
[image]

How can i receive buffer data :
I define this :

```
public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[4000];
```

I have this function :

```
 public void WaitForData(System.Net.Sockets.Socket soc)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pfnWorkerCallBack == null)
                {
                    // Specify the call back function which is to be 
                    // invoked when there is any write activity by the 
                    // connected client
                    pfnWorkerCallBack = new AsyncCallback(OnDataReceived);
                }
                SocketPacket theSocPkt = new SocketPacket();
                theSocPkt.m_currentSocket = soc;
                // Start receiving any data written by the connected client
                // asynchronously
                soc.BeginReceive(theSocPkt.dataBuffer, 0,
                                   theSocPkt.dataBuffer.Length,
                                   SocketFlags.None,
                                   pfnWorkerCallBack,
                                   theSocPkt);
            }
            catch (Exception qqq)
            {

            }

        }
```

And another one :

```
 public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
        {
            try
            {
                SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;

                int iRx = 0;
                // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
                // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
                // by the client
                iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
                string res = GetParameters(socketData.dataBuffer);
}
```

Comment: use `UTF32` instead of `Unicode`

Comment: Exactly 4k bytes is a suspiciously round number. You need to decode only the part of the buffer that has the data in.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary utf32 returns this :�����

Comment: @CharlesMager the problem is the decode method

Comment: better to show how you get buffer to find root of the problem

Comment: This looks like UTF8 data :             byte[] input = {50, 58, 216, 174, 217, 136, 216,
                               180, 32, 216, 162, 217, 133,216,175};

            string output = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input);

Comment: @CharlesMager both of them are 4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use UTF-8:

```
string result = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
```

That looks like Farsi to me. (But I don't speak Farsi.)

The differences between Unicode and UTF-8 are mentioned here: [UTF-8 vs. Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode)

Essentially the length of a character makes the difference.

Comment: It says just خوش آمدید  in farsi that it mean welcome in english :)

Comment: @EhsanAkbar Glad I could help you.  :-)

Answer (score -2):

`string myDecodedString = Encoding.GetEncoding("1256").GetString(buf)`

Comment: {"'1256' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.\r\nParameter name: name"}