# 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSBigMutableString characterAtIndex:]: Index 1258 out of bounds; string length 1176'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> <head><style type=\"text/css\">body {         font-family: Mehr Nastaliq Web; font-size: 22pt; white-space: pre-wrap;  text-align: right;  lang: ar; direction: RTL; -webkit-user-select: none; }</style>     </head><body leftmargin=\"20\" topmargin=\"0\" rightmargin=\"20\" > %@  </body></html>",str];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]  options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType }  documentAttributes: nil error: nil];
self.txtView.attributedText=attributedString;
```

Comment: what is str in your htmlString?

Comment: str is string which is contain  urdu text from file  in it .

Comment: @jaydev Please, add some example of `str` that would crash the code.

Comment: It is not being crashed for every urdu text. I tried with `تم کیسی ہو؟` so please add an example text which will crash the code.

Comment: Adding `<meta charset...` in style tag is not working for me (showing wrong text, characters) I'm just opening the html in firefox browser but adding `<met charset...>` in `<head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <\head>` tag showing correct result. I read it [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1) and this is my [example file](https://pastebin.com/8KGxPSJp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try below, Just try it and let me know it is working or not.

```
NSAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                       options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
                                                            documentAttributes:nil
                                                                         error:nil];
```

If you are uncertain of the correct encoding you should use [NSUTF8StringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1497293-anonymous/nsutf8stringencoding?language=objc)

**UPDATE**

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body { font-family: Mehr Nastaliq Web; font-size: 22pt; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: right; lang: en; direction: RTL; -webkit-user-select: none; meta charset=\"UTF-8\" }</style> </head><body leftmargin=\"20\" topmargin=\"0\" rightmargin=\"20\"> مُدّعا عَنقا ہے اپنے عالَمِ تقریر کا میری تقریر کا مفہوم چونکہ عنقا یعنی معدوم ہے اور معدوم </body></html>";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]  options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType }  documentAttributes: nil error: nil];
_txtView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

It is working perfectly with **NSUnicodeStringEncoding**.

Comment: Please, explain the difference between Unicode and UTF8 encoding if possible.

Comment: You can visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-unicode)

Comment: I know the difference but it should be part of the answer. Also it's not clear from your answer why a specific encoding (UTF8) must be used.

Comment: Hi @PPL i have try this code but now text is not displaying in Urdu format . and text is not readable .

Comment: @jaydev Does your font support it? Did you load the text properly?

Comment: @jaydev Also, you should have `<meta charset=...>` in your html.

Comment: Hi @PPL i have include  <meta charset=...>
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body {         font-family: Mehr Nastaliq Web; font-size: 16pt; white-space: pre-wrap;  text-align: right; lang: en; direction: RTL; -webkit-user-select: none; meta charset=\"UTF-8\"}</style>     </head><body leftmargin=\"15\" topmargin=\"10\" rightmargin=\"15\"> %@  </body></html>",str]; but still its showing wrong string format .

Comment: @jaydev as Sulthan said, Please, add some example of str that would crash the code

Comment: hi @PPL <html><head><style type="text/css">body {         font-family: Mehr Nastaliq Web; font-size: 22pt; white-space: pre-wrap;  text-align: right; lang: en; direction: RTL; -webkit-user-select: none; meta charset="UTF-8" }</style>     </head><body leftmargin="20" topmargin="0" rightmargin="20">  
مُدّعا عَنقا ہے اپنے عالَمِ تقریر کا
 میری تقریر کا مفہوم چونکہ عنقا یعنی معدوم ہے اور معدوم 
 </body></html>

Comment: @jaydev give me some time please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171129/discussion-between-ppl-and-jaydev).

Comment: Adding `<meta charset...` in style tag is not working for me (showing wrong text, characters) I'm just opening the html in firefox browser but adding `<met charset...>` in `<head> <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <\head>` tag showing correct result. I read it [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1) and this is my [example file](https://pastebin.com/8KGxPSJp).

Comment: OK Thanks  @PPL for support

Answer (score 0):

I'm also seeing a crash, even in the most basic of examples.  I was able to track it do doing it when creating UICollectionViewCells for a UICollectionView.  When I pulled it out and ran is prior to updating the list, it worked fine...exact same code.

There seems to be a bug inside iOS related to this, at least is cases when it's called inside a `UICollectionViewDataSource:collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 0):

It needs to add character encoding in Option dict the same as the string encode. Otherwise. It will be unreadable code.

```
NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
```

the whole code is

```
let htmlString = """
    <html><head><style type=\"text/css\">body { font-family: Mehr Nastaliq Web; font-size: 22pt; white-space: pre-wrap; text-align: right; lang: en; direction: RTL; -webkit-user-select: none; meta charset=\"UTF-8\" }</style> </head><body leftmargin=\"20\" topmargin=\"0\" rightmargin=\"20\"> hello world! Arabic.<br/> مُدّعا عَنقا ہے اپنے عالَمِ تقریر کا میری تقریر کا مفہوم چونکہ عنقا یعنی معدوم ہے اور معدوم </body></html>
    """

    let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data:
        htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image]

You also can change the string encoding and the attribute encoding at the same time. The result will be readable, too. Such as unicode.

```
let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data:
                   htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.characterEncoding:String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
               textView.attributedText = attributedString
```