# encodeURIComponent and content-type: 'charset: utf-8'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, encoding

I'm building a `react` application and I use `Node` (with Express) as a proxy-server. I send data from react app to node-express, then in Node I use that data to form URI and to make requests to another server.

My question is this: Shouldn't `'content-type': 'charset: utf-8'` be enough when I send data including greek characters to Node? For example, I make a post request (using Fetch) to Node and I send code 'ΠΕ0001' using the header I already mentioned. Why do I get the error 'Path contains unescaped characters'? When I use `encodeURIComponent` it does work, but why  'charset: utf-8' is not enough?

Comment: **content**-type, the URI is hardly part of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting the header `'content-type': 'charset: utf-8'` is not enough. Essentially with this Header you're just telling the server (Node in this instance), that the data you send is in `utf-8` format, which it should expect anyway.

Your string, however, is in UTF-16 format, because [the letter `Π` needs two bytes to be represented.](https://unicode-table.com/en/03A0/).

[You can read more about character encoding here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-unicode).

Hence you need `encodeURIComponent` first. In our case, `Π` is then represented as `%CE%A0`, which are its byte's representations in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

1. use this method JSON.stringify() to convert data to json object.
2. then pass that json object into encodeURIComponent()
3. then call fetch method