# Which is the first multi-byte UTF codepoint?

Tags: utf, multibyte-characters

I just wanted to know which unicode blocks can be safely used when being limited to single-byte codepoints only.

So, which is the last single-byte codepoint, and which is the first multi-byte codepoint?

Comment: I think you're confusing "Unicode" with "UTF" (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/643694/3141234). I think your answer assumes UTF-8, which is the only unicode encoding that I know that has single-byte values.

Comment: UTF-8 starts generating multiple bytes at U+0080, restricting you to the ASCII subset.  Which is equivalent to not supporting Unicode at all.  It has been done.

Comment: If you used ISO-8859-1 you could use the first 256 codepoints. In most other cases, you'd be restricted to the ASCII subset, which is the first 128 codepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UTF-8, the last single-byte code point is `U+007F`, and first 2-byte code point is `U+0080`.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding