# Unicode char representations in BASH / shell: printf vs od

Tags: bash, unicode, printf, octal, od

I have two correlated ***‘why’*** —***not ‘how to’***— questions:

#### Question 1

While [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/printf-invocation.html) and [`od`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/od-invocation.html) produce same decimal, octal, and hex representations for ASCII characters —

```bash
ascii_char=A

printf "%d" "'$ascii_char"
65
echo -n $ascii_char | od -A n -t d1
   65
echo -n $ascii_char | od -A n -t u1
  65
printf "%o" "'$ascii_char"
101
echo -n $ascii_char | od -A n -t o1
 101
printf "%x" "'$ascii_char"
41
echo -n $ascii_char | od -A n -t x1
 41
```

— ***why*** do they somehow not produce same representations for a Unicode char?

```bash
unicode_char=

printf "%d" "'$unicode_char"
128021
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t d1
  -16  -97 -112 -107
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t d
 -1785683984
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t u1
 240 159 144 149
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t u
 2509283312
printf "%o" "'$unicode_char"
372025
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t o1
 360 237 220 225
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t o
 22544117760
printf "%x" "'$unicode_char"
1f415
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t x1
 f0 9f 90 95
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t x
 95909ff0
```

#### Question 2

While `od` results for a Unicode char are different from those of `printf`, ***how come*** `printf` still knows how to convert `od` results back to a character — while `printf` cannot convert back its own results?

```bash
printf "%o" "'$unicode_char"
372025    # printf cannot convert back its own result
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t o1
 360 237 220 225    # looks different, but printf can convert it back correctly
printf %b '\360\237\220\225'
    # success

printf "%x" "'$unicode_char"
1f415    # printf can convert back this result
printf "\U$(printf %08x 0x1f415)"
    # success
echo -n $unicode_char | od -A n -t x1
 f0 9f 90 95    # looks different, but printf can convert it back correctly
printf %b '\xf0\x9f\x90\x95'
    # success
```

Comment: Please note these are ‘why’ questions — not ‘how to’

Comment: [What is the difference between UTF-8 and Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-unicode) would be a good start. This doesn't have much to do with the shell or the utilities mentioned.

Comment: The "Dog" character, , is Unicode code point U+1F415, which is represented in UTF-8 by the byte sequence 0xF0 0x9F 0x90 0x95. What you're seeing is these two things in a variety of representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the difference you are seeing is the difference between a Unicode **codepoint** and its UTF-8 **encoding**.

`printf` prints **codepoints**, see [POSIX documentation for `printf ... "'"`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html):

> If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be **the numeric value in the underlying codeset** of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.

This number is always the same, no matter if you choose UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, ... `od` on the other hand, has no knowledge of the character codeset. `od` only prints bytes / words (= groups of `-t` bytes), and those are always encoded even if the encoding happens to be the same number as its codepoint (e.g. for ASCII characters in ASCII encoding, or ASCII characters in UTF-8 encoding).

[has the codepoint 12802](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F415). UTF-8 tries to encode codepoints in single bytes (hence UTF-**8**, because 1 byte = 8 bit), but 12802 > 2<sup>8</sup>=256 does not fit into a single byte, so the number is split across multiple bytes, which are marked as special to prevent confusion.  These special markers on each byte lead to the different output from `od`.

If you convert to UTF-32, every codepoint will fit into a single word, allowing you to use `od` to display codepoints:

```
# Assuming little endian system. For big endian systems use UTF-32BE.
echo -n  | iconv -t UTF-32LE | od -An -tu4
128021
```

#### Question 2

With `printf %b '\360\237\220\225'` you (manually) reverse the oct-dump from `od`, so that the original UTF-8 encoding of  is printed to the terminal. Here, `printf` does not care about the character set or encodings at all; the terminal is the one interpreting the encoding.

`printf %o \'`=`372025` cannot be reversed that easily because ...

1. Octal numbers do not align as nicely with bytes as e.g. hexadecimal. For a single byte (2<sup>8</sup>=256) two octal digits are insufficient (8²=64) and three octal digits are too much (8³=512). Hence, if you print 4 bytes as a single octal number (`printf %o`) some digits contain information from two bytes. Therefore you cannot split the octal number into 4 octal numbers (one for each byte) simply by grouping the existing digits. Instead, you have to convert into base 256 and then convert each base-256-digit into base 8 again -- just like you would if you had one big decimal number. That's what `od` does ;)
   You could say, this part is an advanced form of "*Why can `printf` read decimal numbers, but not base-5 numbers?*".
2. The resulting bytes would still have to be encoded in UTF-8, so that your terminal recognizes them. With `printf %b '\360\237\220\225'` this part was not necessary, because the UTF-8 encoded  was never decoded into its codepoint to begin with.

Nevertheless, you can convert the octal representation of 's codepoint back:

```
printf "\\U$(printf %08x 0372025)"  # leading 0 = octal number
```